# AWS Lambda returns empty response on RDS connect - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rds

I have an AWS RDS which is publicly accessible and I want to connect to that RDS using AWS Lambda. I am using API Gateway to create a Rest API named "/hello", which needs to return the RDS connection status.

The Lambda code is given below.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder'),
  api = new ApiBuilder();

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "host",
  user: "user",
  password: "password"
});

module.exports = api;

api.get('/hello', function () {

//any code written here, works perfectly, when this is called

  con.connect(function(err) { //this part doesn't work
    if (err) return err;
    return "connected";
  });
});
```

The database is publicly accessible, even from my local machine. The Lambda function also has the required permissions with AWS RDS.

The response I get on the browser is as follows

```
{}
```

I checked the cloud watch logs, and it is given below.

```
08:16:11
START RequestId: bf804be1-4797-11e8-8b3f-5b09118631a6 Version: $LATEST
08:16:11
END RequestId: bf804be1-4797-11e8-8b3f-5b09118631a6
08:16:11
REPORT RequestId: bf804be1-4797-11e8-8b3f-5b09118631a6  Duration: 34.28 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 26 MB
```

The Lambda function doesn't go past `con.connect(...)` where there is no error being shown anywhere (not even on RDS logs). The API Gateway works, because any code before `con.connect(...)` works perfectly. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@ConfusedCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064972/confusedcoder) explained, this is caused due to `con.connect(...)` being an asynchronous call. Using the context in Lambda is not an option here, as Lambda is being invoked using API Gateway, and that there is no `exports.myhandler` being used in the scenario. Therefore the context object cannot be used to control the flow of Lamda.

```
exports.myHandler = function(event, context) {
   ...
}
```

I tried playing with promises, async await and other techniques until I found a node package named [sync-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-mysql). This makes synchronous queries to a mysql database, where AWS Lambda does not proceed without executing the database call. The updated code is given below, using '`sync-mysql`'.

```
var ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder'), api = new ApiBuilder();    
var MySql = require('sync-mysql');

var connection = new MySql({
  host: "host",
  user: "user",
  password: "password"
});

module.exports = api;

api.get('/hello', function(request) {    
  return connection.query('SELECT * FROM DB.DummyTable');    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) return err;
    return "connected"; 
});
```

This is an asynchronous call. Before connect callback function is called lambda will complete and exit.

Change this to

```
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) context.done(err);
    context.done(null, "connected"); 
});
```

Comment: Please review the [markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and format code examples as code, rather than as blockquotes.

Comment: @ConfusedCoder Thanks for your answer. As you mentioned, it was an asynchronous call and Lambda terminates before it.  Making the entire flow, synchronous, solved the problem.

Comment: @ConfusedCoder there is no context when it comes to API Builder.. Is there a way to achieve this?